# Refreshing the page after executing jQuery function on content

Tags: jquery, ajax, page-refresh, emoticons

I have a jQuery function which applies some formatting to the entire HTML page. I have this function execute successfully.

```
jQuery.fn.emoticons= function(iconfolder) {
    //some operations
};
```

This function purpose is to transform all smilies(:D) to a smiley image. The function has effect on the entire HTML content.

What I am trying to achieve is that, I want this function to be executed every x second and based on it the page content should be changed.

With my limited knowledge on jQuery, I understand that $.ajax() can be used based on a URL and not on a function.

What's the best way to achieve this?

EDIT:

Based on below inputs, I tried this and works. Thanks all.

```
$(function() {
   setInterval(function() { $(".ow_content").emoticons() },5000);
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with setInterval()?

Comment: I am completely new to jQuery. It would be really helpful if you could point me how to execute a function and change the content based on its output. Any link to learn about this will do good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up an interval with `setInterval()`:

```
$.fn.emotions = function() {
   currentHTML = $("body").html();
   newHTML = currentHTML.replace(/:D/,"<img src='/your/image/path'/>");
   $("body").html(newHTML);
};

$(function() {
    waitSeconds = 5;
    setInterval($.fn.emotions, waitSeconds*1000);
});
```

And [here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/f2Vnn/1/) to let you play with it.

Comment: I have updated the actual question with my jQuery that I use.

Answer (score 1):

use setInterval to execute a function after a specified amount of time.

setInterval(someFunction(),1000);

where 1000 is the time in milliseconds which is 1 second.

the function someFunction will run every second in this case.

now using this you can adjust your logic of your code.

Comment: I have updated the actual question with my jQuery that I use.

Comment: Post your function that replaces all occurences of smilies to image. also post the div that contains the smilies.

Comment: http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~skreft/emoticon/ is where I got the function and that div is that of <body> tag of HTML.